# Add a link back to site on 'edit profile' page for users?

Tags: profiles

When users are on the 'edit profile' page, it's hard to tell how to get back to the site. I know you can click on the site name at the top left corner but it doesn't seem obvious. Is there a way to add a link back to the page they were on? Or perhaps a plugin I can install?

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in the `functions.php` file.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Go back to home</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="Go back">Home</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }
```

Check [this tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields) for more detail.

You can put any mark up you want, I just modified the example and have put a link to go to the homepage.
Hope this helps!